# I'm trying to change my span tag when name is submitted

Tags: javascript, input, onclick, submit

I am trying to display the name that user inputs into the span tag - I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

This is my HTML

```js
function getName() {
  var name = document.getElementById(`#inputName`).value;
  console.log(name);
  document.getElementById("#change").innerHTML = name;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div>
    <p>Hello <span id="change"></span>, hope you're having a good day!</p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h2>Please enter your name below:</h2>
  </div>

  <form method=post>
    <input type="text" id="inputName">
    <button type="submit" onclick="getName()">Submit</button>
  </form>

</body>
```

Comment: You don't use the `#` prefix when calling `getElementById`. That's used when calling `querySelector()`

Comment: @Barmar Thank you! I have been mixing the two up and clearly can't catch it yet... I'll try that simple fix

Answer (score 0):

I edited your code, the below version works as expected

document.getElementById() take an id as argument, don't add '#'
Also you don't need a form here

```js
function getName() {
  var name = document.getElementById(`inputName`).value;
  console.log(name);
  document.getElementById("change").innerHTML = name;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div>
    <p>Hello <span id="change"></span>, hope you're having a good day!</p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h2>Please enter your name below:</h2>
  </div>

  <input type="text" id="inputName">
  <button type="button" onclick="getName()">Submit</button>

</body>
```